# Who defines the "store" object?

Tags: ember.js

from this code snippet :

```
Todos.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    createTodo: function() {
      // Get the todo title set by the "New Todo" text field
      var title = this.get('newTitle');
      if (!title.trim()) { return; }

      // Create the new Todo model
      var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
        title: title,
        isCompleted: false
      });

      // Clear the "New Todo" text field
      this.set('newTitle', '');

      // Save the new model
      todo.save();
      }
    }
});
```

which is, in fact, from the [Ember website](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/getting-started/creating-a-new-model/)

Who defines (and where is defined) *this.store* ? I looked in the [Controller class](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html) and in the [DSL](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/49d58530527c9025b4bafe4f937b0c78cfe3818e/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/dsl.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `store` is an Ember Data bookkeeping object.

It has been injected via Ember's [Dependency Injection API](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/) into your application's Controllers and Routes using an [Initializer](http://ember.zone/ember-application-initializers/), so that it can be referenced from any Route or Controller as `this.store`

The `store` is always the same instance of 'store:main' regardless of where it is called from, because it has been injected.